# Python: ftp file stuck in buffer?

Tags: python, ftp

When I download a file with ftplib using this method:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect("host", "port")
ftp.login("user", "pwd")
size = ftp.size('locked')

def handleDownload(block):
    f.write(block)
    pbar.update(pbar.currval+len(block))

f = open("locked", "wb")
pbar=ProgressBar(widgets=[FileTransferSpeed(), Bar('>'), ' ', ETA(), ' ',    ReverseBar('<'), Percentage()],     maxval=size).start()
ftp.retrbinary("RETR locked",handleDownload, 1024)
pbar.finish()
```

if the file is less than 1mb the file will be stuck in the buffer until I download another file with enough data to push it out. I have tried to make a dynamic buffer by dividing the ftp.size(filename) by 20 but the same thing still happens. So how do I make it so I can download single files less than 1 mb and  still use the callback function?

Comment: I think it's likely the issue is that you never close the file, rather than the ftp being buffered.

Comment: You have a valid point there I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wooble stated in comments I did not f.close() the file like an idiot. It fixed the problem.